# Are resurgent theory and the topological recursion truly different or are, in some sense, the same formalism?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, quantum-mechanics

In *Large genus behavior of topological recursion* by B. Eynard, it is described that the topological recursion invariants $F_{g}$ could be a resurgent series (or Borel resummable). Another connection is that both approaches reconstruct the WKB approximation for the harmonic oscillator (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.08913.pdf, https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0405279.pdf). What are main differences between the approaches? Could it be that they derive from the same base formalism?